# ¿Cómo llamar un método de un parámetro tipo object C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando una clase genérica que controlara todos los DataGridView de mi proyecto, pero me a surgido un problema. No se como invocar una función de un parámetro tipo object.

---

### FormPrueva

```
Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Paso una referencia del DataGriView y
   //Una referencia del fromulario
   _dgvm = new DGVManager(ref dgvCBD, this);
}

//Función a Invocar
public void Saludar()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Saludos desde prueba :)");
}
```

---

### Manejador

```
internal class DGVManager
{
    private DataGridView _dgv;
    private MethodInvoker Saludar;

    public DGVManager(ref DataGridView dgv, object instancia)
    {
         this._dgv = dgv;
         Saludar = instancia.GetMethod("Saludar"); //error
         Saludar.Invoke(instancia);
    }
}
```

No tengo mucha experiencia con parámetros tipo object, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En vez de usar reflexión, que no es muy sólido, porque tu código puede cambiar, y solo al runtime te vas a dar cuenta si el método `Saludar` no existe, ...  mejor es definir una interfaz como esta:

```
public interface IMiInterfaz
{
    void Saludar();
}
```

Luego, te aseguras que todos tus formularios implementen esta interfaz.  De esta forma, el código que necesita ejecutar un método de la instancia puede hacerlo de esta forma (de paso, quité el `ref`, que no veo que lo necesites):

```
internal class DGVManager
{
    private DataGridView _dgv;
    private IMiInterfaz instancia;

    public DGVManager(DataGridView dgv, IMiInterfaz instancia)
    {
         this._dgv = dgv;
         this.instancia = instancia;

         this.instancia.Saludar();
    }
}
```

---

Otra opción, que tal vez no sea tan buena como la de arriba en mi opinión, pero que sigue siendo mejor que usar reflexión, es de usar *function delegates*. En ese caso, no necesitarías una interfaz. Solo tendrías que ajustar el parámetro para que reciba na referencia al método `Saludar`, en vez de recibir una referencia al formulario como tal:

```
internal class DGVManager
{
    private DataGridView _dgv;
    private Action saludar;

    public DGVManager(DataGridView dgv, Action saludar)
    {
         this._dgv = dgv;
         this.saludar = saludar;

         this.saludar();
    }
}
```

Y este sería el código para pasar la referencia al método `Saludar`:

```
Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Paso una referencia del DataGriView y
   //Una referencia del método Saludar()
   _dgvm = new DGVManager(dgvCBD, this.Saludar);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @sstan has sido de gran ayuda.